# How to type an apply function that works properly with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types, apply

So, I'm trying to model `pipeline`, `ap`, a custom function that here I call `myMap` that has a "complex" data structure called here `MyNumber`. Of course this is a "simplified" example, the real world code has a similar shape, and I can change all the functions as required.

This is the snippet:

```js
function pipeline<A, B, C>(a: A, ab: (a: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C): C {
    return bc(ab(a));
}

function ap<A, B, Z>(fn: (x: A, y: B) => Z, a: A): (b: B) => Z {
    return (b) => fn(a, b);
}

function myMap<V>(
    numberFn: ((x0: V) => number),
    arr: Array<MyNumber<V>>
) {
    return arr.map(x => ({ n: numberFn(x.n) }));
}

interface MyNumber<U> { n: U }

const myNumbers: Array<MyNumber<number>> = [
    { n: 1 }, { n: 2 }, { n: 3 }
]

console.log(pipeline(
    myNumbers,
    (arr) => myMap(x => x + 1, arr),
    ap(myMap, x => x + 1)
));
```

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxsgpgGxmdAeAQQBpEAhEgYQD4AKAQwC5FjE6AjJ+pggSkQF4qZEmwicOZPoMQUeTCogDeAKERrEAJ3RQQGpKPpt6PHgG5lAX2XLQkWAlbJCJcogBatYGE4APbiQBPJlIpITcSRmY5RBoJEIEwpVV1LR09GLZQxC96ETNLa1toeCQAWwCAWTonADVaZLUwEFK2dA0AMW8Ymh8ABiYarKaWtp4iBtYNDW4pugC8CoCAOWbWjTw6qmU+FXVNbV0kOimAOlLqnoSYxUQu4bXOnpOwPgsTcytlHCg24DoIdCIRYrEbrACqQhuXTBiE+EAQAGcoIhyiC1giZho5gtlqs2nh7m0qEJ+IgANoTKFMACMsJIVMQACY6UpbkwAMyw5QAXWs8LACLgmHQJ0wcAA5jRUBhsLgaBNUXiNAjxnt6FMsuUqshLtIfIgANSIakRDWq9QXLXVEj6vWG408bZmIA)

One of the things you will note is that that the line

```
    (arr) => myMap(x => x + 1, arr),
```

Typechecks alright. This is what I want, and it's currently my solution (although I have found that if I complicate the types just a little bit, this also breaks). So my goal is to make this line work:

```
    ap(myMap, x => x + 1)
```

But I had no luck so far. Perhaps it's something with conditional types or some other craziness, but really, I have no idea of where to search.

Comment: I fiddled around with this for a bit but had no luck. The issue stems from here:
`Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(x0: unknown) => number'`. So really, I think it's because `numberFn: (x0: V) => number` is not the same as this `x: unknown`. I don't know if that's helpful but hope it might lead to another clue.

Comment: I don't get what you're doing in that `pipeline()` call. `myNumbers` is `MyNumber<number>[]`, and `arr => myMap(x=>x+1, arr)` takes a `MyNumber<number>[]` and returns a `number[]`.  So then your third parameter should take a `number[]`, but that's not what `ap(myMap, x => x+1)` takes, right?  It's also expecting a `MyNumber<number>[]` input, but you're giving it a `number[]`.   So I'd expect an error there.  Is this really a [mcve]?

Comment: Anyway I'd probably proceed like `type MySpecificMap<V> = (numberFn: (x0: V) => number, arr: MyNumber<V>[]) => number[];` and then `ap(myMap as MySpecificMap<number>, x => x + 1)`. TypeScript only has some [very basic support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) for higher order generic functions like `ap` applied to `myMap`, so when its inference fails you need to help it out.  If you want I can make this an answer, but I'd like to understand the `pipeline()` issue first.

Comment: @jcalz Yep, I messed up the example a little bit (fixed it now, my code is quite different from this but the issue is "isomorphic"). So yea, I guess I will have to stick to casting, or using normal functions.